# Валидность введенного номера тел и суммирование всех цифр пока не останется одна

Tags: java

Выполняю учебное задание. Помогите советом, что и как лучше реализовать.

Задача:

Пользователь вводит номер тел, программа считывает пока номер не будет корректен (в моем случае реализована проверка всего лишь на длину номера, хотя чем больше проверок, тем лучше). После введенного валидного номера, необходимо суммировать все цифры, пока не останется одна (Пример: 0671111112, сумма 21, результат 3). И как результат вывести данное число строкой (Пример: результат 3, ответ "Three").

Мой текущий код:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Dima on 22.10.2016.
 */
public class InputNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int sum = 0;
        int sum1 = 0;
        int res = 0;
          BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Введите номер телефона. В формате: ----------");
        while (true) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            char[] array = line.toCharArray();

            if (array.length < 10) System.out.println("Ошибка. Недостаточно цифр.");
            else if (array.length > 10) System.out.println("Ошибка. Много цифр.");

            else if (array.length == 10) {
                for (final char c : array) {
                    if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {
                        System.out.println("Ошибка. Вы ввели символ вместо цифры.");
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                    }

                    sum = sum + Character.getNumericValue(c);
                }

                //System.out.println("Sum " + sum);
                while (sum != 0) {
                    //Суммирование цифр числа
                    sum1 = sum1 + (sum % 10);
                    sum /= 10;
                }
                //System.out.println("Sum1 " + sum1);
                while (sum1 != 0) {
                    //Суммирование цифр числа
                    res = res + (sum1 % 10);
                    sum1 /= 10;
                }

                break;
            }
            }


       // System.out.println("res " + res);
            switch (res){
                case 1:  System.out.println("One");
                    break;
                case 2:  System.out.println("Two");
                    break;
                case 3:  System.out.println("Three");
                    break;
                case 4:  System.out.println("Four");
                    break;
                case 5:  System.out.println("Five");
                    break;
                case 6:  System.out.println("Six");
                    break;
                case 7:  System.out.println("Seven");
                    break;
                case 8:  System.out.println("Eight");
                    break;
                case 9:  System.out.println("Nine");
                    break;
            }

                    }
             }
```

Comment: И в чём же ваш вопрос?

Comment: @Roman, Вопрос ТС был удален при изменении вопроса.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Проверку номера телефона я бы сделал с помощью регулярных выражений:

```
public static boolean isNumberValid(String number) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[\\d]{10}$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(number);
    return matcher.matches();
}
```

Метод `isNumberValid(...)` проверяет соответствие введенного номера маске вида `XXXXXXXXXX` (10 цифр).

Ввод номера телефона можно реализовать так:

```
String stringNumber;
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

do {
    System.out.println("Введите  десятизначный номер телефона");
    stringNumber = reader.nextLine();

    if (!isNumberValid(stringNumber)) {
        System.out.println("Введены некорректные данные: номер должен состоять из 10 цифр");
    } else {
        break;
    }
} while (true);
```

Подсчет суммы цифр введенного номера так (*если я правильно понял, необходимо суммировать все цифры, кроме первой*):

```
long number = Long.parseLong(stringNumber.substring(1));
int firstSum = 0;

do {
    firstSum += number % 10;
    number /= 10;
} while (number > 0);
```

Подсчет суммы `secondSum` цифр полученного числа `firstSum` так:

```
int secondSum = 0;

do {
    secondSum += firstSum % 10;
    firstSum /= 10;
} while (firstSum > 0);
```

А последнюю задачку я оставлю Вам. Подумайте, каким может получится конечное число, которое необходимо вывести прописью. Может здесь нужно что-то более сложное, чем `switch - case`?...

И еще: видите выше два практически одинаковых фрагмента кода? Дабы избавиться от дублирования, данный код нужно вынести в отдельный метод, а потом просто пользоваться этим методом.

Да и вообще, не стоит все вот так в одном методе писать. Разделите решаемую задачу на подзадачи, каждый метод будет решать отдельную подзадачу.